# Login Node & Compute Node abstracted through User File System?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc

So I have a python script that I can using login node directly `python run.py` as well as by sending `sbatch` command.

The result from that scripts appears in a home folder regardless that its compute node or login node.

So is compute node and login node abstracted by means of file system? Compute node process the scripts and pushes the result in my file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have a distributed filesystem or at least a shared filesystem available to your Compute and Login nodes. i.e The both share the same home directory structures so changes appear coherent across the cluster.